# chrome extension opening tabs very slow on production

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I built a chrome extension that opens certain site instances in new tabs using  `window.open(url, '_blank');`
It seems to work a little slow on development but very slow on production.
I tried to open the chrome app using --process-per-tab and --process-per-site, according to the chrome's article: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models#1_Process_per_Site_Instance

But nothing seems to work. I noticed the first time I opened the chrome with the beginning url then it looks fast.

Comment: How are you opening them?

Comment: @Daniel Herr using  window.open(url, '_blank');